# Consequences of using Spring 4 in Servlet 2.4 container

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

Based on the Spring framework version 4 documentation link
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-4.0.html its mentioned that Servlet 3.0 is the base for Spring 4 but still its possible to deploy in servlet 2.5.

Below is an extract.

> 3.4 Java EE 6 and 7 Java EE version 6 or above is now considered the baseline for Spring Framework 4, with the JPA 2.0 and Servlet 3.0
>   specifications being of particular relevance. In order to remain
>   compatible with Google App Engine and older application servers, it is
>   possible to deploy a Spring 4 application into a Servlet 2.5
>   environment. However, Servlet 3.0+ is strongly recommended and a
>   prerequisite in Spring’s test and mock packages for test setups in
>   development environments.

My question is,

1. Can we use it in Servlet 2.4 container? To be more specific i am trying to deploy in jboss-4.0.5 application server.
2. What are the consequences of using spring 4 in legacy servlet containers?

Comment: Not sure about all the consequences but one thing sure you wont be able to use WebApplicationInitializer to bootstrap your application.

Answer (score 0):

1. As you already discovered from the reference documentation, Spring 4 requires Servlet 2.5.
2. It won't work.